# passing user defined java objects to velocity scriptengine

Tags: velocity, scriptengine, aem, sling

im using velocity template with CQ5. the velocity scriptengine i ve installed identifies pre-defined CQ objects. i would like to know how to pass user defined java objects to the velocity script engine.
I tried something similar to this:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy

but it doesnt work..Kindly help me to solve this situation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use `VelocityContext` to pass object parameter like `context.put("name_of_parameter", yourOBject);`
In my example `test.temalate` , `$person.address` mean call address getter method of person object.

Example : Try as below

Person.java
    public class Person {
        private String name;
        private String address;

```
    public Person(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.init();
        Template template = ve.getTemplate("test.template");
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("person", new Person("Jhon", "London"));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(context, writer);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

test.template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>$person.name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>$person.address</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You will get output as below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Jhon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>London</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "Getter method" was the key word. Thank you!